# How to invoke Application.MainWindow Property

Tags: c#, wpf

This property driving me nuts , i have a button in my wpf form,what am trying to achieve here is

When i click button, disable the main window and pop up the message box.

this the code behind

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is Button)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false;
                    MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "test");

                }));
           }
    }
```

Initialize my main window

```
protected override void InitializeShell()
    {                    
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
```

It throws exception "'[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[1].(2)'."at "Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false;" .

Here is the stack trace of few lines

```
       at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.VerifyPathIsAnimatable(PropertyPath path)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope, DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary clockMappings, Int64 layer)
```

If i bypass then it display message box but am wondering why it throw exception at isEnable=false ?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

My shell.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Webster.Client.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Webster.Client"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF"         
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Webster.Client.Controls"
    xmlns:inf="clr-namespace:Webster.Client.Infrastructure;assembly=Webster.Client.Infrastructure"
    Title="Webster - News Segmentation and Encoding" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Normal"
    Icon="/Webster.Client;component/Resources/film_clip64.png" SizeToContent="Manual" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    MinWidth="390" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<!-- window -->
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/background.png"  Stretch="Fill"/>
</Window.Background>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type inf:ExtendedHeader}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=IconUri}" Width="16" Height="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Storyboard x:Key="InTransition">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Logo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5000000" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-72"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="-157"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.5,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Logo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-50"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="-101"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0,1" KeyTime="00:00:02.5000000" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="MainToolbar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="MainToolbar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="100"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="100"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="0" KeySpline="0,0.495999991893768,0.504000008106232,1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource InTransition}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<!-- content grid -->
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="627*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- logo -->
        <Canvas x:Name="Logo" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock 
                Text="" 
                TextAlignment="Center" 
                TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                Foreground="#FFC4CFD6" 
                FontSize="50" 
                Opacity="0.85" 
                Canvas.Left="9" 
                Canvas.Top="6" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Height="60" 
                Width="{Binding ElementName=Logo,Path=ActualWidth}"
                FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Canvas>

        <!-- main bar -->
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MainToolbar" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainToolBarRegion}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="1">
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10, 0, 10, 10">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

        <!-- content -->            
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>

            <Controls:AnimatedTabControlWebster 
                x:Name="StoryTab"
                SelectedIndex="0"  
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShellTabItemStyle}" 
                Background="{StaticResource headerBarBG}" 
                cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainRegion}"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PositionSummaryTab" IsEnabled="True">
            </Controls:AnimatedTabControlWebster>
        </Grid>

        <!-- footer -->
        <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"                     
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                Margin="0 0 10 0"
                >
            <Button Name="btnExit" Click="btnExit_Click">Exit</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"     
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                >
            <ItemsControl 
                    cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainFooterRegion}" 
                    />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you set `Application.MainWindow`?

Comment: here is the way i set the main window,updated in my question

Comment: your code works perfectly fine here, what framwork version are you using?

Comment: sa_ddam213, am using Framework 4.0

Comment: works here on 3.5,4.0,4.5, What is `Shell` is that a derived Window of from an external lib?

Comment: @sa_ddam213, shell is one of my XAML form (i would say its the base window of the form)

Comment: @sa_ddam213, i added stack trace for your view in the question

Comment: @Usher what's the definition of the `Shell` property? I mean `(Shell)this.Shell` why are you doing that?

Comment: have you tried casting as `Shell` before calling `IsEnabled = false;` or even `Application.Current.MainWindow.SetValue(Window.IsEnabledProperty, false);`

Comment: @HighCore, honestly i didn't write this code but what my assumption is ,he is trying to assign shell.xaml as a current window

Comment: @sa_ddam213,i tried with "Application.Current.MainWindow.SetValue(Window.IsEnabledProperty, false);" got the same exception

Comment: Do you have access to the `Shell` code it looks like you have a running animation that is not stopped correctly, perhaps its attached to a trigger in the IsEnabled property, But based on your stacktrace you seem to have an animation tring to animate a property path that it cannot access maybe due to disabling the window.

Comment: @sa_ddam213,seems to be you are right,i will post the full code of shell.xaml in the op

Comment: Workaround, Maybe you could disable the Window Content and not the Window itself `(Application.Current.MainWindow.Content as FrameworkElement).IsEnabled = false;`

Comment: Thanks a lot all your help guys but unfortunate after use the workaround code still am getting the same exception